# Curve_fit returning wrong parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I've got a little project for my college and I need to write a method which fits an array to some function, here's it's part:

```
   def Linear(self,x,a,b):
       return a*x+b


   def Quadratic(self, x, a,b,c):
       return a*(x**2)+b*x+c

   def Sinusoid(self,t, a, gam, omega, phi, offset):
       return np.e ** (gam * t) * a * np.sin((2 * np.pi * omega * t) + phi) + offset


   def Fit(self, name):
       func= getattr(App, name)
       self.fit_params, self.covariance_matrix = curve_fit(func, self.t, self.a, maxfev= 100000)
```

But it returns absolutely wrong values and also doesn't even work for Sinusoid function (ptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated `warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated')`. I've already checked if it's not an issue with getattr function but it works correctly.

I'm running out of ideas where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

Linear, Quadratic and Sinusoid do not need self, you can define those as staticmethod:

```
#This is the decorator use to define staticmethod
@staticmethod
def Linear(x,a,b):
     return a*x+b
```

The same applies to other methods (except Fit).

It will help when they are called in the future. When you call them with curve_fit(func,...), for example, if func is Sinusoid, what you are doing is
curve_fit(Sinusoid, ...) and not curve_fit(self.Sinusoid,...). When curve_fit use Sinusoid, the first argument may be understood as the self, therefore, you get and error.

If you define

```
@staticmethod
def Sinusoid(t, a, gam, omega, phi, offset):
      return np.e ** (gam * t) * a * np.sin((2 * np.pi * omega * t) + phi) + offset
```

a, gam, omega, phi and offset are constants to fit. Therefore, when you call curve_fit, you need to pass this constants as params:

scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, absolute_sigma=False, check_finite=True, bounds=- inf, inf, method=None, jac=None, **kwargs)

To clarify: The first argument is the func, the second is your experimental data for x, and the third, is the data for y. And after that all the others kwargs, like maxfev. I don't know if self.a is the data for y, or if you want to set an initial value for a. I'm going to guess you want to set the initial value of a. You need to do it like this: p0=[x1,x2,x3,x4,..., xn] where xi is the initial value of the i-th constant. If you don't pass p0 as an argument to curve_fit, the default value for each constant is going to be 1. But here it comes the last problem:
The diferent functions use a diferent number arguments, so for the first one, Linear, you need to do p0 = [a,1]. For the second, p0 = [a, 1, 1]. And for the last one, the Sinusoid one, p0 = [a, 1, 1, 1, 1]
I don't really know if you can pass p0 = [a] to all of the functions and curve_fit will magically understand. But try so and if curve_fit doesn't let you, use condictionals:

```
def Fit(self, name):
    if func = Linear:
        p0 = [a,1]
    elif func = Quadratic:
        p0 = [a,1,1]
    elif func = Sinusoid:
        p0 = [a,1,1,1,1]

    self.fit_params, self.covariance_matrix = curve_fit(func, self.t, self.y_values, p0=p0,  maxfev= 100000)
```

Where self.y_values is the experimental data as an array-like element.

If self.a is the data for y you can cut all of this mambojambo and let Fit define as it currently is. But don't forguet the @staticmethod in the other functions.

Hope this solves your problem.